# PostScript interface for non-PostScript printers with IPP and IIS?

Tags: iis, postscript

Is it possible to use IPP and IIS to provide a PostScript interface for a printer that does not natively support PostScript?

The aim here is to provide a generic interface for printing over IPP, so that clients can standardize on a single driver (PostScript) instead of having to download drivers for different printers. I could do this with CUPS, but would like to know if it is feasible with IIS, as well.

Answer (score 0):

IPP via IIS can only work for job-submission. You would still need an additional postscript-renderer in order to print to a printer which does not support postscript. CUPS comes with a set of default filters that could do the job for you.

Answer:
It is not possible to use IPP or IIS to provide a 'generic-postscript-printer-interface'.

Answer (score -1):

While IPP uses HTTP as a transport it is a different protocol. Without substantial filters/extensions to IIS you can't use it s an IPP server.

Comment: Huh? From http://download.microsoft.com/download/e/6/c/e6c750cd-87b6-4350-be1b-035dd42c5552/InternetPrint.doc:
The only prerequisite to enable Web-based printer management and Internet printing is that you install and run Internet Information Server (IIS) on the print server. IIS is installed by default with Windows 2000 Server versions and it can also be installed as an optional component on Windows 2000 Professional, Windows XP, and Windows Server 2003.

The linked document provides a fairly straightforward how-to for enabling IPP with IIS.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't know MS already provided the "substantial extensions". Thanks for the Pointer.

Comment: @markusk link is dead

Comment: @RedShift Seems Microsoft has taken it down. Archived version that still works: https://web.archive.org/web/20110125051943/https://download.microsoft.com/download/e/6/c/e6c750cd-87b6-4350-be1b-035dd42c5552/InternetPrint.doc